# Каждое слово в строке с заглавной буквы?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Как сделать каждое слово в строке с заглавной буквы?

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос** — например, что именно у вас не получилось. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @user232151  Определить начало слова и перевести первый символ слова в прописной символ.:)

Answer (score 4):

Да без проблем :)

```
char s[] = "sdghvh jhsbvjs jhsgcs nm  cdgvs jhvsd  1hjhj jhbvjh6";
for(char last = ' ', *c = s; *c; last = *c++)
{
    if (last == ' ' && *c != ' ') *c = toupper(*c);
}
puts(s);
```

Comment: Без проверки `&& *c != ' '` по идее тоже должно сработать. Хотя наверное будет не так канъонично.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Да, просто будет лишние пробелы в верхний регистр переводить :)

Comment: Ну цифры то он все равно переводит )) Мож тода `isalpha` ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian :)

Comment: Тяжело наверное будет преподу объяснить этот код ))

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Почему?...

Comment: Это неработающий код, к сожалению. С *символами* в Си всё достаточно плохо. Разве что для одной кодовой таблицы...

Comment: @0andriy, если кодировка явно не задана, будем считать -- *ascii* (и тогда работает).

Comment: @avp, да, при таком условии.